# RTL Problem in my WordPress plugin on elementor repeater

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes, elementor

As a plugin, I'm developing a elementor widget. But when I go to RTL mode (Arab League) then my repeater is repeating starts from the end. That means my first repeater showing at the last/end. I'm using polylang plugin for the Arabic language. From the Languages option When I choose the text direction right to left (Arab League) then my repeater item also reaction turn over on view. Also when I use the plugin as normal (With deactivate polylang [Arab League]) then that's fine.
Note:- I also used Essential Addon. Here have no problem. Elementor repeater also. But when I'm using the Happy Addon or others (Any repeater widget) then I face the problem. You can try this plugin with polylang (Arab League). Then I think you can face the problem also.
Now, As a developer how can I solve the problem?

[The plugin link](https://github.com/Ferdaussk/image_accordion.git)
Screenshot: [The plugin overview when active RTD mode](http://programmerferdaus.rf.gd/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/rtl-need.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue here bro, I'm facing problems with Polylang and  RTL as well, and I hope they fix it as soon as possible.

Anyways, try the rollback plugin and roll back your polylang version to an older version, one that is working properly on one of your sites, and don't forget to use the ployland elementor connector plugin.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).